# mysql ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file?

Tags: mysql

My Vps mysql wont boot , when i attempt to command service mysql start i got this error

```
root@## [/var/lib/mysql]# service mysql start
Starting MySQL... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/***.***.com.pid).
```

this is `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
set-variable = 100
max_connections=100
safe-show-database

#userstat_running=on
query_cache_limit=4M
query_cache_size=64M
query_cache_type=1
max_user_connections=100
interactive_timeout=30
wait_timeout=100
connect_timeout = 20
thread_cache_size = 256
key_buffer_size=16M
join_buffer_size=2M
max_heap_table_size=16M
low_priority_updates=1
max_allowed_packet=128M
max_seeks_for_key=100
record_buffer=2M
sort_buffer_size=16M
read_buffer_size=16M
max_connect_errors=10
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency=4
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
tmp_table_size= 64M
set-variable=table_cache=100
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M
skip-name-resolve

open_files_limit=6050
[mysqld_safe]

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

and this is the error log

```
140227 21:23:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140227 21:23:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140227 21:23:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140227 21:23:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
140227 21:23:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140227 21:23:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140227 21:23:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140227 21:23:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140227 21:23:41 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140227 21:23:41  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140227 21:23:42 InnoDB: 5.5.35 started; log sequence number 2155325
140227 21:23:42 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'set-variable=100'
140227 21:23:42 [ERROR] Aborting

140227 21:23:42  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140227 21:23:43  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2155325
140227 21:23:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140227 21:23:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/***/***.com.pid ended
```

how to fix this ? any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
140227 21:23:42 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'set-variable=100'
```

remove the line from configuration file

Comment: i did sir still same problem

Comment: What does the log file tells you know? Fix all errors it reports, and your server will start.

Comment: yes i did so and also i removed `record_buffer=2M` and its worked ill mark ur answer when ill be able to , thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Try these commands :

```
root@vps [~]# killall -9 mysql mysqld
root@vps [~]# /etc/init.d/mysql  start
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

on MAC    End any `mysql` or `mysqld` task (or other) in your `Activity Monitor` application.

or check you error by

```
tail -f /usr/local/mysql/data/XXXXX-MacBook-Pro.local.err
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user and group of */var/lib/mysql* is **mysql** recursively.

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql