# MySql ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql

I inherited a computer that previously had MySql server installed and then uninstalled (apparently, it ran fine before the uninstall).  I am in Database class, so I tried to install it again and now I get the error:

*Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Computer.local.pid).*

I looked online and saw this error happened to others, but either a)I couldn't figure out how to do the fix or b)the fix didnt work for me.

**I tried**(from http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/mysql-error-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/):

Computer:/ computer$ /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart

And I get this error:
*ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL*

*. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Computer.local.pid).*

**I am not sure what they are telling me to do here:**

Remove /etc/my.cnf or just back it up for now and restart:
sudo mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.bak

because I get this error when I type:

*Computer:/ computer$ cd /usr/my.cnf*

*-bash: cd: /usr/my.cnf: No such file or directory*

I also see from: [mysql ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077231/mysql-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file)
That there are error logs and the my.cnf file, but I am not sure to access them.

---

The MySql I downloaded: mysql-5.7.10-osx10.9-x86_64.dmg

I am on a mac version 10.7.5

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file

Comment: I read this and it did not help me.

Answer (score 32):

Mostly this is a permission issue

**Step1:** Check the error file first.

```
tail -f /usr/local/mysql/data/*.err
```

**Step2:** Do a complete shut down or kill the process. Confirm that no mysql process is running

```
mysqladmin -uroot shutdown
sudo killall mysqld 

ps -ef | grep mysql
```

**Step3:** Give permisiions

```
sudo chown -RL root:mysql /usr/local/mysql
sudo chown -RL mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/mysql/data
```

**Step4:** Start mysql

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

Comment: Rockstar...I just found the old installation of MySql in another folder and the my.cnf is located in there.  That is the only my.cnf folder...perhaps that is causing me the problem?

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Worked like a charm for me

Comment: Where do I send the case of scotch?  I've been looking at convolluted solutions all day with no success. yours was most simple and just worked!  Thank you!

Comment: `brew services start mysql`

Comment: Didnt work for me :(

Comment: `chmod: /usr/local/mysql/data: No such file or directory`

Comment: I don't have that directory either ( /usr/local/mysql/data ) I brewed my mysql, but cant find the equivalent log anywhere :(

Comment: Does not work in OSX 10.15 Catalina