# I can't start MySQL Server and Workbench error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I have just installed [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

After installing both, I can see the "MySQL" icon in System Preferences. But if I try to start MySQL Server it asks me the password, but then nothing happens. 
So I tried to start MySQL Server from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

But it gave me this error:

```
Starting MySQL
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/MBP.local.pid).
```

Can anyone help me please?

Before all this I've not had any problems starting and stopping MySQL, but I forgot the MySQL password so I had to uninstall MySQL and install it again because I needed to use Workbench. But obviously without the MySQL password it didn't work. Is there a way for me to recover the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if a mysql process already exists or not `ps -ef | grep mysql`
2. If yes, Kill the process `kill -9 PID` or `killall -9 mysql mysqld`
3. Check the owner ship of the mysql data directory is  `mysql:mysql`
4. Then try to start mysql server  `sudo mysql.server start`
5. If this do not resolve the issue. Then have a look in the mysql `.err` file

Check out: [MySql ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026553/mysql-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/35027185#35027185)

Comment: I killed mysql process already existed and then restart my PC. Now all work fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The sudo line will try to run MySQL as root -- bad idea.  Hopefully the mysql.server file was copied to /etc/init.d during install so all you should have to do is /etc/init.d/mysqld start